# nginx adding multiple trailing slashes - returning 500

Tags: nginx

I was configuring my nginx server to serve static files (sveltekit build)
The page just worked when you loaded the homepage first, but if you were on a subpage and reloaded you got a 500

I changed the try_files configuration to

```
location / {
    root /home/david/sveltekit/build/;
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/;
}
```

and it started serving the html files but without the hydrations needed

the error log showed this for example:

> rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/_app/immutable/assets/app-eb16993b.css///////////",

to me it seems obvious that nginx is hanging '/' slashes at the end of the uri, but I don't get why

I finally got it to work by getting rid of multiple slashes with the following conf:

```
# https://serverfault.com/questions/1014050/how-to-remove-the-trailing-slashes-from-a-url-with-nginx
rewrite /((?U).*)(/+)$ /$1 redirect;
```

But I'd still would like to know what was wrong with my conf

Comment: You are redirecting to `$uri/` which continually adds a trailing `/`. The `$uri/` term has a **different meaning** when it's not the final parameter of the `try_files` statement. See [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I went to the documentation before posting but it's not really clear what the search behavior is. I read the documentation for root and it seems obvious to me that if I set location to / and root as path/build then a request to /_app/immutable/path/document.css wouldn't even need to go through try files, but that wasn't the case apparently for some reason

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution to serving static files from a sveltekit build would be the following

```
location / {
    root /home/david/client-v2/build;
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /index.html;
    # https://serverfault.com/questions/1014050/how-to-remove-the-trailing-slashes-from-a-url-with-nginx
    # rewrite /((?U).*)(/+)$ /$1 redirect;
}
```

the community discourages from using "rewrite" and the "redirect" was causing bugs by redirecting too much on some uris